# Converting special timestamp containing milliseconds to epoch

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a timestamp in following format:

```
Feb 21 15:46:23.997
```

I am trying to convert this to EPOCH timestamp. The last three digits after decimal are ms, don't want to lose those in conversion. The issue here is the timestamp is not in generic format, so having some issues converting that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a custom format. Your date string does not have a year so `to_datetime` will default to 1900, which you must manually correct:

```
pd.to_datetime('Feb 21 15:46:23.997', format='%b %d %H:%M:%S.%f') \
    .replace(year=2020) \
    .timestamp()
```

Result:

```
1582299983.997
```

Comment: Do I have to run a loop to change all the dates in the dataframe column (I have 3 million rows), or is there a built in function which takes the whole column and changes the format?

Comment: No. you can call `pd.to_datetime` on a list, a Series or a dataframe column too.The function is vectorized.

Comment: Thanks. One issue I am seeing after running following command:
df_delta["Converted"] = pd.to_datetime(df_delta["Time"], format='%b %d %H:%M:%S.%f')

It is throwing following error:
ValueError: unconverted data remains:

Comment: I am ok with year changing to 1900 as I just going to do delta time anyway - so I have removed the replace part